# how to differentiate a dynamic link from one another in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, database

I have an icon that when clicked, it shows a side navigation bar that loads the column 'years' from a table in the database which makes each year a link.

```
2012
2013
2014
2015
```

When I click 2012, it should go to new.php. The same goes for the rest but it should load different data per year. I know I have to use AJAX for this. However, since it is dynamically loaded, I have a problem on how to differentiate one from the other since the name of all the links is the same.

here is my code snippet:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

    <?php
        $res= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT year FROM years_table");
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
    <a name="year_name"><?php echo $row['year'];?></a>

    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

This is the part that I have a problem with:

```
<a name="year_name"><?php echo $row['year'];?></a>
```

Comment: I just formatted your post correctly. Now you overwrote it.

Comment: Did you just delete your code in favor of posting an image of it? Where's my pitch fork

Comment: @IsThisJavascript - Why do things the right way when you can do it the wrong way?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sometimes I write SQL injectable code to fit in with the cool kids.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that it was displayed the wrong way. The problem is still the same anyway. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing smething like this:

```
<a class="year" data-year="<?php echo $row['year'];?>"><?php echo $row['year'];?></a>
```

Then you would get

```
<a class="year" data-year="2012">2012</a>
```

With class being the selector of all your link a data-year being the value you want to send through ajax

Comment: May I know what date-year is?

Comment: Have a look there https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

data-* correspond to a custom attribute in HTML